# How do I make tabs in a tabview transparent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How do I make a tabview so that the tabs are a bit transparent so that you
can see the content of a Listview being hosted by the tabview?

[image]

So far I tried making the tabs/buttons transparent by setting the alpha, but I think
that the way the Tabhost is made there isn't anything behind the buttons, so making it
transparent will only show a black background

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the tab widget. And use buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="woopra" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>       
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="gone"/>            
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="64dip">
            <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0" android:id="@+id/dashboard_tab" 
                android:onClick="tabHandler" android:text="Dashboard"/>
            <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0" android:id="@+id/visitors_tab" 
                android:onClick="tabHandler" android:text="Vistors"/>
            <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0" android:id="@+id/chat_tab" android:onClick="tabHandler"
                android:text="Chat"/>
            <Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0" android:id="@+id/reports_tab" 
                android:onClick="tabHandler" android:text="Reports"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
                 android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here Ive used 4 buttons instead of the tabwidget. And in the button's onclick I use
something like
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

Setting alpha to the buttons should work.